# Using PowerShell in System Recovery?

Tags: windows-7, windows, system-recovery

I need to turn on system protection so I can run a system recovery.

It seems to only be possible to do this through the PowerShell:

> http://answers.Microsoft.com/en-us/Windows/forum/windows_7-system/enable-system-protection-from-command-line/d9e94566-a5eb-4e30-bcda-a04b513099fe

When I start PowerShell through a cmd prompt in the System Rescue Options, I get:

> "The subsystem needed to support the image type is not present"

Any ideas on how to either turn on system protection or to run the PowerShell in recovery?

Answer (score 1):

Many applications, and frameworks do not run from Windows PE (The environment that runs whilst in the setup program).

However, I think this (unfortunately) is a pointless exercise. When you turn system protection off, it deletes all previous restore points. So, even if you were to turn it on, there will be no benefit to it.

Comment: well the interesting thing is that it shows the most recent restore point being the day before i started having issues.. im not sure why it got turned off i have the feeling it wrongly thinks its turned off